# How can Pycharm (with matplotlib) show me my graphs in the same Py charm, next to my code?. Not in additional windows

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

i am using Matplotlib with Pycharm in a Mac osx. When I am making a graph, and I code plt.show() pycharm opens another window. And if there is 2 graphs, to see the 2nd one I have to close the first one. And I want to see both together.

There is a option to show the two graph in the same window, where my code is?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

This link may help:
[IPython magic commands](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ipython.html)

Using Jupyter notebooks you can achieve what you want by using `%matplotlib inline`. It seems from the link above that PyCharm may have some way to enable this same functionality.

See also: [Inline plots in the scientific view](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002149279-Switching-to-inline-plots-in-the-Scientific-View-)